# Setting up audio queue for ffmpeg rtsp stream playing

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm working on an rtsp streaming(AAC format) client for iOS using ffmpeg. Right now I can only say my app is workable, but the streaming sound is very noisy and even a little distorted, far worse than when it's played by vlc or mplayer.

The stream is read by av_read_frame(), decoded by avcodec_decode_audio3(). Then I just send the decoded raw audio to Audio Queue.

When decoding a local aac file with my app, the sound seemed not so noisy at all. I know initial encoding would dramatically affect the result. However at least I should try to have it sounded like other streaming clients...

Many parts in my implementation/modification actually came from try and error. I believe I'm doing something wrong in setting up Audio Queue, and the callback function for filling Audio Buffer.

Any hints, suggestions or help are greatly appreciated.

// --info of test materials dumped by av_dump_format() --

```
Metadata:
    title           : /demo/test.3gp
  Duration: 00:00:30.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16
aac  Advanced Audio Coding
```

// -- the Audio Queue setup procedure --

```
- (void) startPlayback
{
    OSStatus err = 0;
    if(playState.playing) return;

    playState.started = false;

    if(!playState.queue) 
    {

        UInt32 bufferSize;


        playState.format.mSampleRate = _av->audio.sample_rate;
        playState.format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        playState.format.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
        playState.format.mChannelsPerFrame = _av->audio.channels_per_frame;
        playState.format.mBytesPerPacket = sizeof(AudioSampleType) *_av->audio.channels_per_frame;
        playState.format.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(AudioSampleType) *_av->audio.channels_per_frame;
        playState.format.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sizeof(AudioSampleType);

        playState.format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;        
        playState.format.mReserved = 0;


        pauseStart = 0;
        DeriveBufferSize(playState.format,playState.format.mBytesPerPacket,BUFFER_DURATION,&bufferSize,&numPacketsToRead);
        err= AudioQueueNewOutput(&playState.format, aqCallback, &playState, NULL, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &playState.queue);

        if(err != 0)
        {
            printf("AQHandler.m startPlayback: Error creating new AudioQueue: %d \n", (int)err);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUFFERS ; i ++)
        {
            err = AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescriptions(playState.queue, bufferSize, numPacketsToRead , &playState.buffers[i]);

            if(err != 0)
                printf("AQHandler.m startPlayback: Error allocating buffer %d", i);
            fillAudioBuffer(&playState,playState.queue, playState.buffers[i]);
        }

    }

    startTime = mu_currentTimeInMicros();

    err=AudioQueueStart(playState.queue, NULL);

    if(err)
    {

        char sErr[4];
        printf("AQHandler.m startPlayback: Could not start queue %ld %s.", err, FormatError(sErr,err));

        playState.playing = NO;
    } 
    else
    {
        AudioSessionSetActive(true);
        playState.playing = YES;
    }           
}
```

// -- callback for filling audio buffer --

```
static int ct = 0;
static void fillAudioBuffer(void *info,AudioQueueRef queue, AudioQueueBufferRef buffer)
{

    int lengthCopied = INT32_MAX;
    int dts= 0;
    int isDone = 0;

    buffer->mAudioDataByteSize = 0;
    buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount = 0;

    OSStatus err = 0;
    AudioTimeStamp bufferStartTime;

    AudioQueueGetCurrentTime(queue, NULL, &bufferStartTime, NULL);


    PlayState *ps = (PlayState *)info;

    if (!ps->started)
        ps->started = true;

    while(buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount < numPacketsToRead && lengthCopied > 0)
    {
        lengthCopied = getNextAudio(_av,
                        buffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity-buffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                        (uint8_t*)buffer->mAudioData+buffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                        &dts,&isDone);

        ct+= lengthCopied;

        if(lengthCopied < 0 || isDone) 
        {
            printf("nothing to read....\n\n");
            PlayState *ps = (PlayState *)info;
            ps->finished = true;
            ps->started = false;
            break;
        }

        if(aqStartDts < 0) aqStartDts = dts;

        if(buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount ==0)
        {
            bufferStartTime.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
            bufferStartTime.mSampleTime = (Float64)(dts-aqStartDts);//* _av->audio.frame_size;

            if (bufferStartTime.mSampleTime <0 ) 
                bufferStartTime.mSampleTime = 0;

            printf("AQHandler.m fillAudioBuffer: DTS for %x: %lf time base: %lf StartDTS: %d\n", 
                    (unsigned int)buffer, 
                    bufferStartTime.mSampleTime, 
                    _av->audio.time_base, 
                    aqStartDts);

        }

        buffer->mPacketDescriptions[buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount].mStartOffset = buffer->mAudioDataByteSize;
        buffer->mPacketDescriptions[buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount].mDataByteSize = lengthCopied;



        buffer->mPacketDescriptions[buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount].mVariableFramesInPacket = 0;

        buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount++;

        buffer->mAudioDataByteSize += lengthCopied;
    }

    int audioBufferCount, audioBufferTotal,  videoBufferCount, videoBufferTotal;
    bufferCheck(_av,&videoBufferCount, &videoBufferTotal, &audioBufferCount, &audioBufferTotal);

    if(buffer->mAudioDataByteSize)
    {

        err = AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters(queue, buffer, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0, NULL, &bufferStartTime, NULL);

        if(err)
        {
            char sErr[10];
            printf("AQHandler.m fillAudioBuffer: Could not enqueue buffer 0x%x: %d %s.", buffer, err, FormatError(sErr, err));

        }

    }

}




int getNextAudio(video_data_t* vInst, int maxlength, uint8_t* buf, int* pts, int* isDone) 
{

    struct video_context_t  *ctx = vInst->context;
    int    datalength            = 0;

    while(ctx->audio_ring.lock || (ctx->audio_ring.count <= 0 && ((ctx->play_state & STATE_DIE) != STATE_DIE)))
    {

        if (ctx->play_state & STATE_EOF) return -1;        
        usleep(100);
    }

    *pts = 0;
    ctx->audio_ring.lock = kLocked;

    if(ctx->audio_ring.count>0 && maxlength > ctx->audio_buffer[ctx->audio_ring.read].size)
    {    
        memcpy(buf, ctx->audio_buffer[ctx->audio_ring.read].data,ctx->audio_buffer[ctx->audio_ring.read].size);

        *pts = ctx->audio_buffer[ctx->audio_ring.read].pts;

        datalength = ctx->audio_buffer[ctx->audio_ring.read].size;

        ctx->audio_ring.read++;        
        ctx->audio_ring.read %= ABUF_SIZE;        
        ctx->audio_ring.count--;

    }
    ctx->audio_ring.lock = kUnlocked;

    if((ctx->play_state & STATE_EOF) == STATE_EOF && ctx->audio_ring.count == 0) *isDone = 1;

    return datalength;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for the distorted sound is simple packet loss, which RTSP can be susceptible to, especially over wireless connections.

I suggest you look into configuring ffmpeg to use TCP based connections when possible instead of the default RTP/UDP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are downloading or decoding audio inside your Audio Queue callback, NUM_BUFFERS and/or bufferSize may need to be much larger to cover worse-case network latency and jitter.  Or you could pre-decode audio outside the audio callback, and queue up enough data before the callbacks to handle the download and decoding time and variance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the note. 

Downloading and decoding are processed in another thread. What is done here is only to fill the audio buffer when needed. It's very possible to wait until we have something to fill (in getNextAudio()). I just don't get it why the output audio got distorted and was full of noise.